# Do i keep my SO point when a question gets migrated?

Tags: support, migration

**Case:** One of my questions got migrated, but there were upvotes on it. OR
Such a question got migrated an i answered it earning upvotes.

**Do i keep my SO reputation (till it got migrated) in SO when a question gets migrated?**

Answer (score 2):

If you enter `http://stackoverflow.com/reputation` in the browser's address bar does the final number at the bottom of the page match (more or less) your current reputation? (There may be other deleted posts which could result in a reduction).

Also get the question id and check the report to see if it contains lines like this:

```
2    765616 (5)
```

where `765616` is the id of your question.